# Java FK with Hibernate and a Hard-Coded Key

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, foreign-keys

I am trying to create a FK relationship between 2 models in my Java code using Hibernate. 1 of the values of the composite key is hard-coded depending on the table name. How can I tell Hibernate to hard-code this value for this model?

[image: Data Structure for Meta Data]

### [image: Meta Data Overlap]

[image: Teacher Data]
[image: Senior Teacher Data]

The FK should validate that the AGE within the appropriate tables (Teacher or Senior Teacher) fall within the correct group. For example, if I tried to create a Teacher with an AGE of 16 the service should reject that because the 16 is not a valid age for the TEACHER as shown in the META_AGE_GROUP table. However, 16 is a valid age for the STUDENT table.

I tried to simply use the code like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TEACHER")
public class Teacher {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "key.age")
    private MetaAgeGroup age;

@Entity
@Table(name = "META_AGE_GROUP")
public class MetaAgeGroup {

    @EmbeddedId
    private MetaAgeGroupKey key;

    @Column(name = "AGE_GROUP_DESC")
    private String description;


@Embeddable
public class MetaAgeGroupKey implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7130496764273819801L;

    @Column(name = "AGE")
    private Short age;

    @Column(name = "AGE_GROUP_NAME")
    private String group;
```

But I am getting this Exception:

> Referenced property not a (One|Many)ToOne: 
>        com.whee.school.jpa.model.MetaAgeGroup.key.age in mappedBy of 
>        com.whee.school.jpa.model.Teacher.age

Is there any way that I can take the Age from the database when selecting a Teacher and map it to the `MetaAgeGroup` FK by providing the `AGE_GROUP_NAME` equal to the table name I am selecting from without putting the table name in the actual data record? More specifically, I do NOT want to put a column that stores the value 'Teacher' in the `TEACHER` table. I want to use the table name itself in the FK relationship.

Is this possible?

---

**UPDATE**

If I change the Teacher Model like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TEACHER")
public class Teacher {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumns(value = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "age", referencedColumnName = "AGE"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "fk", referencedColumnName = "AGE_GROUP_NAME")})
    private MetaAgeGroup age;
```

Then Hibernate has no issues associating the Teacher to the MetaAgeGroup. However, my data set has a column with the table name inside it; like I am trying to avoid. But this is the only way I can get my application to compile.

[image: Fk Column Added]

Comment: how did you map the MetaAgeGroup entity?

Comment: Sorry I forgot that. I added it to the post under Teacher model.

Comment: Is this an existing database or are you creating the schema?

Comment: Existing database.